# "could not find or load main class"-error when running jar-file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I created a simple Java program that prints a result to an Excel-file. If I run the class file (called "Calculation.class") using the command

```
 java Calculation
```

it all works fine and the result is printed into the specified Excel cell. Then I created a JAR-file using the following command:

```
     jar cmf manifestfile.mf myprogram.jar Calculation.class
```

The jar-file was created in the same folder. However, if I run the jar-file by double-clicking on it, the result is not printed to the Excel-file.
In order to see what was going wrong I ran the jar file in the terminal using the command

```
 java -jar myprogram.jar
```

I received the following error message:

```
 could not find or load main class
```

However, I included the Calculation class (which contains the main() method) in the manifest file. ... I tried several things for the manifest-file ...

First try (1 single line followed by carriage return):

```
 Main-Class: Calculation
```

Second try (3  lines followed by carriage return):

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Created-By: 1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation)
 Main-Class: Calculation
```

Third try (2  lines followed by carriage return):

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Main-Class: Calculation
```

Each time I got the same error message.

What's going wrong here ? Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the .jar file?

Comment: If your main class is `Calculation` then why the class file you are including is `myprogram.class` ?? If there is only one class in the JAR i.e. `myprogram.class` and it contains main method then you should have `Main-Class: myprogram`. And if `Calculation` is your class having main method then it should be present in the JAR, but clearly it is not present from the code you have should shown, so `could not find or load main class` is expected. Check both the things I have told, either of them has to be true.

Comment: Thank you for the comment ... Actually, the name of the class file is actually "Calculation" ... (I wanted to avoid confusin so changed the name of the class file for this question (but confused myself in the process) ... I edited the question accordingly ... Bottom line is: name of class file is the same as name of class containing main method.

Comment: Do you have version info your manifest file? (Manifest-Version: 1.0)

Comment: Have opened the JAR file and tried to verify `Calculation` class is present ?? If it is present then could be some issue with your manifest file - try this content in your manifest file - `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Calculation`

Comment: On a side notes, your JAR creation command is wrong or your have put here wrong .. It should not be `java` command but a `jar` command, so here is the right one - `jar cmf manifestfile.mf myprogram.jar Calculation.class` ..

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I corrected the mstake in the question ... in the original, I did not make the mistake.

Comment: Check your manifest file to see if it is looking for your main class?

Comment: Calculation class is present in the jar file ... tested it using "java -jar myprogram.jar"

Comment: I tried the following in the manifest-file:
First try:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Calculation
 ----- Second try:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Calculation .... it always gave the same error message.

Comment: scerrecrow, I checked the content of the manifest-file (i.e. the lines contained in it, see comment above) ... is there something more I can do?

Comment: @steady_progress Hi, is it possible for you to put the entire manifest file content in the post instead on the comment?

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: Could you do following - (1.) Execute this command `jar tf myprogram.jar` and provide the generated log. (2.) Open the JAR using a ZIP software and open the MANIFEST.MF file and view its content to ensure everything is correct.

Comment: the log is:
first line: META-INF/ 
second line: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
third line: Calculation.class

Comment: This log looks good and expected. What about #2 I mentioned ?? Did you try to open the JAR and see the content of `MANIFEST.MF` ??

Comment: ok ... just managed to open the jar file with winzip ... the content of the MANIFEST.MF file is:
first line: "Manifest-Version: 1.0"
second line: "Created-By: 1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation)"
third line: "Main-Class: Calculation"
... the second line was not written by me ... it got automatically added

Comment: the problem is still not solved ... doesn't have anybody any idea what could be wrong here ?